# Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printing, java.util.scanner

I was trying to run my program and it shows up this in the console, I am trying to achieve or to show in the console that there is a new user was created in the ATM but it only shows the name of the user, the id, and no date shown. Here is the block of code that seems to be the problem according to the console

**User.Java**

```
        //print log message
        System.out.printf("New user %s, %s with ID %s created. \n",
               firstName, this.uuid );
```

**Bank.java**

```
public User addUser(String firstName, String lastName, String pin){
    User newUser = new User(firstName, lastName, pin, this);
    this.users.add(newUser);

    //create a savings account fot he user
        Account newAccount = new Account("Savings", newUser, this);
        newUser.addAccount(newAccount);
        this.accounts.add(newAccount);
    return newUser;
    }
```

**Atm.java**

```
  User aUser = theBank.addUser("Carl", "Bustamante", "0605");
```

This what says on the console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iah2.png)

Hoping for your help, thank you.

Comment: In your print message `System.out.printf("New user %s, %s with ID %s created. \n", firstName, this.uuid );` you have specified three `%s` but you have passed only two arguments later(`firstName` and `this.uuid`).  Please pass the third one.

Comment: ohhh cheers mate! it solved the problem. I'm kinda new to programming so i think i overseen it now it works perfectly fine! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Root Cause

- `System.out.printf` & `String.format` require the same number of arguments to be supplied as the specifiers, otherwise this Exception is triggered.
- In your case, you supplied 3 specifiers of `%s` but only 2 arguments, `firstname` & `this.uuid`:

  - `System.out.printf("New user %s, %s with ID %s created. \n", firstName, this.uuid );`

From the context, it sounds like you were going for firstname & last name then UUID?

#### A Note on Easy Prevention/Detection

Modern IDE's, such as IntelliJ, generally highlight these types of easily-missed errors.

Usually with detailed descriptions to both define the problem, and provide a solution.

E.g. for your own code:
[image: IDE highlighting the error]